# Is it possible to add registry entries to the wine registry and make illustrator work?

Tags: 10.10, wine, adobe

I haven't done this kind of work before but I really need Adobe Illustrator to get work on ubuntu! I don't care if it is cs3 or 4. I have installed CS3 and 4 master collection on windows and with wine on ubuntu can't run it (yes, no registry entries added to the wine!) I can copy all the needed file to the **/home/prasad/.wine/dosdevices/C:** directory with hidden files included, but how to add registry entries to them? (windows registry editor like thing to wine) is it possible to make illustrator run in ubuntu like that, i tried to install Master collection but it failed number of times. I use ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WineHQ rates this working as "garbage"

[source](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20)

I would recommend Oracle VM VirtualBox and setting up a Windows environment to install Adobe Illustrator to.

Its located in the Ubuntu Software Center or through Synaptic.

Comment: so is it impossible to install a program by adding registry values to the registry? i've tried VM but it is too slow

Comment: give it a try but don't be disappointed if it doesn't work.

Comment: Windows depends on Partition letters, such as c:, d: etc.... but in ubuntu it's sda1, sd2 etc... will I have to edit all the registry entries to that format to work properly?

Comment: good question! I don't know. Lets see if some else knows the answer.

Comment: Thanks man!, you always have an eye on me!+1 for you (As always)

Answer (score 2):

Wine comes with its own implementation of the Windows Registry Editor, which can be started with the following command:

```
wine regedit
```

It looks and behaves mostly the same as Microsoft's implementation of the tool, so if you are used to that version, you shouldn't have too much trouble.