# How to install road-rash game into linux? how to install registry files manually into wine?

Tags: permissions, wine, games

How to install old road rash game into wine and manually edit registry. I try it by following way but i unable to fix it. Provide simple step by step guide for it.
I read:- 
http://thehacklist.blogspot.in/2010/05/road-rash-on-linux-using-wine.html
[Is it possible to add registry entries to the wine registry and make illustrator work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116923/is-it-possible-to-add-registry-entries-to-the-wine-registry-and-make-illustrator)
https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/using-regedit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install wine-development

   ```
   sudo aptitude purge wine
   rm -rf    $HOME/.wine
   sudo aptitude install wine-development
   ```
2. Download Road Rash

   ```
    https://kat.cr/road-rash-t1890054.html(the link is broken)
    https://gamesnostalgia.com/download/road-rash_/1724 (roadrash_win.7z 
    16.4MB, this link is ok)
   ```
3. Install Road Rash

   ```
   wine-development Road\ Rash.exe
   ```
4. Edit registry, go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Electronic Arts\RoadRash 95] change "Path"="C:\somepath" to "Path"="C:\yourpath"

   ```
   regedit-development
   ```

Comment: 4th step in answer is mandatory? If yes can you provide some realistic example for paths? How to find out paths?